# How to increase application performance that use mysql with caches or other database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have api written on Laravel, I use mysql as database, and I have performance issue when getting data from table with 3-4 million rows. Sql functions that i use are: AVG, SUM, COUNT also i use group by and where exists statements in my queries very much. All tables are indexed, so i think that there is few chances to boost the performance by adding or changing table indexes. How can i boost the performance using caches, or is there any DATABASE that can do such calculations on bug amount of data faster than sql.

Comment: If you don't know the answer, you should consult with a DBA. For short engagements consider services like [Codementor](https://www.codementor.io), [Savvy](https://www.savvy.is), or [airpair](https://www.airpair.com).

Comment: you can do explain and query to check if the indices actually in use in your query check https://deliciousbrains.com/optimizing-laravel-database-indexing-performance/

Comment: also for object caching https://voltagead.com/practical-object-caching-in-laravel/